# Tikz: cycling through a foreach function

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to cycle through the terms in a `\foreach` function. Here's my code:

```
\foreach \n in {cdof,cc,cdus,ads,aiw} \draw [->] (\n) |- ($(\n)+1$);
```

However, as expected, this breaks down as there is no term after 'aiw'. I've tried putting in a condition (`$((\n)+1)<6$`) but this doesn't work. Is it possible to put conditions in the `\foreach` function? Or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that condition? I don't think I get it exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my first try, I did not notice you want to connect nodes via arrows. There are two options (see the figure below). You can connect all of the nodes via one zig-zag line with an arrow at the and (red line) or with multiple lines with an arrow at each node (black).

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (D) at (3,3);

    % FIRST OPTION
    \draw[red,thick,->] (A)
    \foreach \i in {B,C,D}{
        |- (\i)
        };

    % SECOND OPTION
    \foreach \n [count=\i] in {A,B,C,D}
    {       
        \ifnum\i>1
            \draw[thick,->] (Q) -| (\n);
        \else \fi
        \coordinate (Q) at (\n);
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

Older version - I will leave it here since it uses a slightly different method and may also be interesting to consider.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} % prepare dummy coordinates
    \coordinate (A-\i) at (\i,\i);

\draw[thick] (A-0) node[fill=black] {\color{white}0}
foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
    |- (A-\i) node[fill=black] {\color{white}\i}
    };      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sometimes, (here too) you can even further simplify the code as

```
\draw[thick] (A-0)
foreach \i in {0,...,3}{ % different range than in the original code
    |- (A-\i) node[fill=black] {\color{white}\i}
    };
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also without any conditions, provided that you name your nodes in a sequentially numbered way like `a-x` with `x` ranging from `0` to `4`, e.g., if you have five nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt] 

\foreach \i in {0,...,4} % prepare dummy coordinates as @Ondrian
  \coordinate (a-\i) at (\i,\i);

\foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,...,3}
  \draw [->] (a-\i) |- (a-\j);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cycle through a list and `remember` the first one to be used after the last one (or the last one to be used before the first one), `remember` option is what you need.

Following code taken from AboAmmar answer has been slightly modified to remember `previous` element from the list. `initially` sets the element previous to first element.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.7pt] 

\foreach \i in {0,...,4} % prepare dummy coordinates as @Ondrian
  \coordinate (a-\i) at (\i,\i);

\foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 4)] in {0,...,4}
  \draw [->] (a-\j) |- (a-\i);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]